# What was the airline attendants looking at in LED display before light off in A320

Tags: airline-operations, takeoff, weight-and-balance

I was journeying on Indigo Pune-COK back and forth. At both the times, I noticed airline attedants looking at some LED display which seemed to be some sort of balance scale. At first, I thought they might be looking to check at some sort of weight distribution sensor to check whether things are distributed evenly all across the aircraft or something else. I am not sure now but would be glad if somebody could chime in. The plane is and was single class 180 Airbus A320. https://seatguru.com/airlines/IndiGo/IndiGo_Airbus_A320.php

Edit : Update - . Both times, it was before the takeoff procedure. The LED/LCD display was located above the flight attendants chair on the left . The chair on which they sit in the front during take off. The one which is located to left of the refreshments and just before the pilot cabin/cockpit.  The LED/LCD display was above the flight attendant's chair at eye-level.

While I'm sure it had to do with probably some sort of avionics controls they were looking at, I am not sure what.

Comment: Can you add some more details? At what point before/during/after the flight did you see this? Where exactly was the display located in the aircraft?

Comment: @Pondlife I edited and updated the question with bit more specifics, does that give some additional idea/info ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can the Flight Attendant Panel do?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/what-can-the-flight-attendant-panel-do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The panel you have seen near the forward left door was most probably the Flight Attendant Panel of the CIDS (Cabin Intercommunication Data System). It looks like this: [picture of the CIDS panel at jetphotos.com](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/136204)

In the lower part, it has two LED scales which can show the quantities in the fresh and waste water tanks of the aircraft. If I remember correctly, they will only light up while the IND ON pushbutton next to them is pressed.

The cabin crew will routinely check those water levels to ensure e.g. the lavatories can be used.

Comment: solves my question, thank you.